# Android ActionDrawer header

Tags: android, fixed

basically i have a sliding menu on left side of my application. when user clicks on the home button ...that sliding menu shows up. in that sliding menu there is section with items. on click of item i show him a certain fragment. i want on top of this actiondrawer...to have a fixed header and that fixed header not to be scrollable. so when user scrolls, it scroll through items, section...but not the header that is on top of the sliding menu. 
how can this be done?

> ```
>                public View onCreateDrawerView() {
>     DuxAutoScrollListView listDrawer = new DuxAutoScrollListView(this);
>     listDrawer.setCacheColorHint(0);
>     listDrawer.setAdapter(new ListDrawerAdapter(getDrawerItems()));
>     listDrawer.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(0x80737373));
>     listDrawer.setDividerHeight(1);
>     listDrawer.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, 
>                     long id) {
>             mDrawer.setArrowAnchor(view);
>             // mDrawer.closeDrawer();
>             positionAnchor = position;
>             displayView(position);
>         }
>     });
>     listDrawer.setOnScrollChangedListener(new                 
>                  DuxAutoScrollListView.OnScrollChangedListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onScrollChanged() {
>             mDrawer.getContainer().invalidate();
>         }
>     });
>     return listDrawer;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The drawer should have one single LinearLayout with vertical orientation and two children:

1. The fixed top part should then contain another Layout (pick whatever you need) that will not be scrollable.
2. The second child is your DuxAutoScrollListView